# Is Québec City a proper French designation?

Tags: usage, toponymes, langage-informel

*Sport 24.com*, affiliated with *Le Figaro* since 2003 and bought over by the group in 2006, published in May 2019 [an article](http://sport24.lefigaro.fr/tennis/roland-garros/actualites/felix-auger-aliassime-la-nouvelle-attraction-des-internationaux-de-france-958632) about the new tennis sensation Félix Auger-Aliassime. In it we can read the following:

> Coach au Togo, son pays natal, avant de rallier le Canada en 1996, son père Sam, resté entraîneur et désormais propriétaire d’une académie de tennis à **Québec City,** a formé son fiston jusqu’à ses 14 ans avant qu’il rejoigne le centre national d’entraînement de la fédération, Tennis Canada, basé à Montréal.

I was surprised to find the name of the capital city of the province of Quebec designated as **Québec City** in French, especially from a publisher like *Le Figaro*. On a historical basis, the city was founded by French settlers in 1608. Furthermore, I found [here](http://www4.rncan.gc.ca/search-place-names/search?q=Quebec&category=O) that the very common English designation *Quebec City* is not even recognized by the Government of Canada as the official name for the city, neither in French (as easily expected) nor in English. The only official designation is *Québec*, and while the province’s official name in English is *Quebec* (without the accent), the accent spreads to sub-units like the *Historic District of Old Québec* or the *Québec Garrison Club National Historic Site of Canada*.

Is this a common practice to refer to the city of Québec as **Québec City** in (near-)formal French, or is this poor practice?

Comment: Je n'avais jamais lu ou entendu *Québec city* en français, dont le suffixe me parait assez déplacé et inutile. En cherchant un peu, je suis tombé la dessus: https://generationvoyage.fr/visiter-quebec-city-faire-voir/ ...  et, du Figaro aussi: http://golf.lefigaro.fr/actualite/monde/combat-des-chefs-a-mexico-city-945643 alors que le français n'a pas besoin de distinguer l'état du Mexique de sa capitale, au contraire de l'espagnol ou l'anglais.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 La source du toponyme semble en effet venir de la langue algonquine, selon plusieurs sources. Ceci dit, l'appelation *Québec* est officielle (pour la ville) en français et en anglais (selon la norme canadienne pour ces deux langues, bien entendu, les autres pays (et tout particulièrement leurs entreprises privées, et même celles d'icitte, d'ailleurs) font comme ils veulent (de toute évidence)).

Comment: J'ai écrit à _Sport 24_ et à _generationvoyage.fr_ pour leur faire part de mon mécontentement.

Comment: For what it's worth, official or not, here in Ontario and probably elsewhere in Canada we Anglophones say "Quebec City" almost every time, unless the context makes it crystal clear that we're only taking about cities (e.g. it occurs in a list of populous cities in Canada or something). Similar for Mexico City. New York might be the exception only because one talks about the city so much more than the state... Anyhow, I'm sure the English usage must be a factor, even though it's odd to see it in Le Figaro...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 I mean that Anglophones here when speaking English generally say /kwə'bɛk/ for the province and /kwə'bɛk/ City for the city. In terms of spelling, no italics or accent.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Got it. Maybe one day I'll ask on the English language assets whether /kəˈbɛk/, /keɪˈbɛk/ is popular a pronunciation, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Qu%C3%A9bec) lists them...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 In North-Western Canada, I tend to hear /kwəˈbɛk/ or /kweˈbɛk/ only from Americans, and then they tend to adjust to the local pronounciation when people say it their usual way, that is: /kəˈbɛk/. So it seems like the way to say it varies from location to location. A bit like “poutine”, I guess.

Comment: On dit simplement [Québec](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sATRhhqUiAc).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I knew that much that Québec is commonly used in French, but the use of Québec City in a French text, by an entity owned by *Le Figaro*, tends to claim there is a choice in designation. I gather you don't use this designation, nor did Robert Charlebois in his song, but individuals stand small beside such a massive corporation as *Le Figaro*, and our opinions (yours, mine, even Charlebois’) matter little in that big picture. We probably need more evidence to support a claim that Québec City was a poor choice, a mistake or an infamy.

Comment: @Montéedelait I have seen Quebec City in [english](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/16/travel/36-hours-in-quebec-city.html), and I suspect the journalist translated something and didn't bother to translate correctly Quebec City to Québec. That would not be the first time I see poor translations in french newspapers (I have more experience with Le Monde though).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ne dit-on pas aussi [*la Vieille Capitale*](https://www.journaldequebec.com/2019/05/26/corey-bass-fait-le-boulot), après tout? L’existence de la désignation *Québec* n’empêche pas la désignation *la Vielle Capitale*. J’en déduis que l’on doit fonder son rejet de *Québec City* par autre chose que l’existence de *Québec*.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for taking the time to reply and expand your claim. You should probably write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> — [...] Votre réponse positive, dans une heure, par votre trompette,
>   avec le retour du mien, est ce que je vous demande sur le péril qui
>   pourra s'en suivre. [Extrait de la [missive](https://books.google.ca/books?id=h88BAAAAMAAJ&dq=je%20n'ai%20point%20de%20r%C3%A9ponse%20%C3%A0%20faire%20%C3%A0%20votre%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral%20que%20par%20la%20bouche%20de%20mes%20canons%20et%20%C3%A0%20coups%20de%20fusil&pg=PA171#v=onepage&q=bouche%20de%20mes%20canons&f=false) de Sir William Phips
>   délivrée par le lieutenant Thomas Savage.]
>  [— **Bienvenue à Québec
>   City !!!** (à genoux) ou ;]
>  — Je ne vous ferai pas tant attendre. Dites à
>   votre général que je ne connais point le roi Guillaume et que le
>   prince d'Orange est un usurpateur. [...] Non, je n'ai point de réponse
>   à faire à votre général que par la bouche de mes canons et à coups de
>   fusil; qu'il apprenne que ce n'est pas de la sorte qu'on envoie sommer
>   un homme comme moi; qu'il fasse du mieux qu'il pourra de son côté,
>   comme je ferai du mien. [Réponse de Louis de Buade, comte de
>   [Frontenac](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Buade_de_Frontenac#Bataille_de_Qu%C3%A9bec) et de Palluau, 16 octore [1690]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Qu%C3%A9bec_(1690))

---

En français, il n'existe qu'une seule manière de référer officiellement à la ville de Québec (dans la province de Québec, au Canada) : [**Québec**](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/toposweb/Fiche.aspx?no_seq=51718). Rien n'empêche de parler de la ville : *la ville de Québec*. On peut ainsi s'exprimer intelligemment en français :

> Coach au Togo, son pays natal, avant de rallier le Canada en 1996, son
>   père Sam, resté entraîneur et désormais propriétaire d’une académie de
>   tennis *dans la ville de Québec/à Québec* [...] (extrait de la version non vassalisée de l'article du s*ports24/LeFigaro*)

Ceci dit, on peut noter que des anglophones rédigeant un article en langue anglaise comprennent parfaitement, et mieux que d'autres par ailleurs, l'inutilité totale de l'emploi informel de *Quebec City* en français, vu les ressources propres à notre langue (la notion de genre et l'article défini) :

> According to the Government of Canada, the Government of Quebec, and
>   the Geographical Names Board of Canada, the names of Canadian cities
>   and towns have only one official form. Thus, Québec is officially
>   spelled with an accented é in both Canadian English and French. [voir lien dans la question]
>
> In English, the city and the province are officially distinguished by
>   the fact that the province does not have an accented é and the city
>   does. Informally, however, the accent is usually omitted in common
>   usage, so the unofficial form "Quebec City" is used to distinguish the
>   city from the province. In French, the names of provinces are gendered
>   nouns and the names of cities are not, so the city and the province
>   are already distinguished by the presence or absence of a definite
>   article in front of the name. For example, the concept of "in Quebec"
>   is expressed as "à Québec" for the city and "au Québec" for the
>   province.
>
> [ Wikipédia, article [*Quebec City*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_City#Name_and_usage) en anglais, notes omises. ]

*Québec City* est à mon avis un calque de mauvais goût, pitoyable et dégradant de l'anglais informel que se veut remédier à cette incurie l'ajout de l'accent aigu ; à mi-chemin entre nulle part et un stationnement, c'est à mon avis une aberration linguistique poseuse et à-plat-ventriste qui a recours à un besoin de différenciation inexistant en français, qui présume de l'ignorance absolue du lecteur pour la géographie, qui fait preuve d'un mépris flagrant de l'histoire de la République française et de la Nouvelle-France et de celle de la plus grande nation francophone en Amérique. *Québec* est la capitale nationale du *Québec*, province du Canada. Au [Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu%C3%A9bec), 80% des gens ont le français comme langue maternelle ; à Québec, *le berceau de la civilisation française en Amérique* ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu%C3%A9bec_(ville)#Francophonie)), 94,1% des gens ont le français comme langue maternelle. Combien d'entre eux emploieraient *Québec City* pour nommer la ville où siège l'Assemblée nationale du Québec ? À l'évidence même des anglophones s'exprimant en français ne s'acoquineraient d'un emploi aussi minable et infâme ; ni même les robots de Google et DeepL.

---

En résumé non aucunement. Il s'agit plutôt de *Québec*.

Comment: La version dévassalisée serait jolie avec la désignation *ZeFigaro*, ne pensez-vous pas? Un énorme merci pour cette réponse claque sua yeule, je n’en attendais pas moins de votre rigueur et de votre vigueur.

Comment: @Montéedelait Le ton de la réponse est un peu exagéré mais j'ai trouvé ça complètement inacceptable et abrutissant que des francophones emploient ça. Je vois un peu ça comme quelqu'un qui déciderait de marcher avec une béquille comme accessoire de mode. Généralement quand en Europe on emploie des anglicismes bien leur norme pour ces emplois est différente, on aime ça, et parfois je digère de travers la _cranberry_ mais là je me suis étouffé avec. En plus avec la prononciation ça va faire _siti_ un peu comme dans ouistiti, ça diminue le son, ça fait _petit singe_, j'ai mon ostie de voyage !

Comment: Enfin ça ressemble à une translittération en langue anglaise de [québécité](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17566663).

Comment: I had to wait for a bit to accept. My feelings were pretty stirred up and I didn't feel it was appropriate to accept your answer simply because it stated what is also my opinion and my frustration on the subject. A few weeks later, I'm not so upset anymore, but I still feel something was painfully ridicule in the paper, and it deserved such a strong reply. Merci!

Comment: @Montéedelait C'était un bon réflexe d'attendre. De toutes façons la sélection est peu importante, ce qui est bien c'est d'avoir la réponse de Laurent et donc les deux côtés de la médaille. La réaction des francophones d'Europe à l'anglicisme m'exaspère complètement. Je peux pas comprendre pourquoi _city_ est plus attrayant que _cité_ ou _ville_. Quand c'est du vocabulaire courant, bof, mais la ville de Québec, c'est un sacrilège inacceptable à mon avis, j'ai pas de mot. Disent-ils la _City of Light_ sacrement ? Les anglophones du Canada entre autres semblent plus sensibles à la question.

Comment: l'emploi des anglicismes en France et au Québec est apparemment un vieux débat. Il semblerait que dans le langage courant les uns et les autres n'hésitent pas à en employer, mais qu'ils ne soient pas les mêmes. En France on va faire du shopping avec son petit-ami, au Québec on va magasiner avec son chum.

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est vrai pour le langage courant et c'est un bon exemple. Il y aussi une histoire, une relation et une perception différente avec la langue anglaise. Autant ce peut-être acceptable familièrement à l'oral pour certains termes, autant ça me choque quand ça devient plus formel et à l'écrit (titre d'emploi, toponyme, nom technique des sports, doc technique, science, droit etc.). Surtout quand un équivalent clair, simple et ancien existe en français, comme avec _sponsor_ /commenditaire. Ou différemment quand ça touche qqc. que j'associe à la nourriture/gastronomie etc. _cranberry_.

Comment: @LaurentS. Voire quand ça touche à l'expression de sentiments, _cash_. Quand ça touche des objets comme des pièces de métal ça m'affecte possiblement moins (_bolt, nut, washer_). Que des impressions. J'aime bien l'anglais et je le parle plutôt bien mais je déteste le voir supplanter ma langue sans raison, comme j'ai déjà dit je trouve ça affecté, déplaisant au son (comme entendre des troupes hollandaises sur son territoire), artificiel et ignorant. Mais j'emploie bien des mots anglais à l'oral mais pas à l'écrit. Quand ça devient 1/2 je préfère parler anglais directement tant qu'à faire.

Comment: @LaurentS. On peut aussi tourner la page sur notre dispute antérieure. Je suis désolé pour mes propos offensants. Par ailleurs je n'ai pas changé d'avis sur le sujet. Il y a sans doute une voie du milieu, la période dans laquelle nous vivons s'y prête peu.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Je crois qu'on peut clore le débat présent sur le fait que ce "Québec city" en Francais est particulièrement inapproprié. Quand à notre dispute antérieure elle est déjà oubliée, même si je pense que la nuance est plus que salutaire, justement dans notre période. Désolé d'avoir suscité une telle réaction. Si cela peut vous consoler, suite à notre discussion j'ai initié le même débat dans mon entourage et les avis sont là aussi très divisés :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it is a common practice and indeed from a source like le Figaro you could expect them to just use "à Québec" which is more correct and also not too ambiguous as the region would imply saying "au Québec". You could also expect the readers of this paper to be litterate enough to get the difference right away.

That said, although apparently not official (and I trust your research on that, I didn't do any research myself), using "Québec city" discards any misunderstanding for sure, and seems widely used in English.

Comment: Sure, "Québec City" is fine in English, but it ridiculous in French. If they want to clear misunderstandings along the same lines, they could always say "la ville de Québec", which is perfectly fine, and actually not uncommon in certain contexts, in Québec.